# Final field instead of accessors in enum

Tags: java, enums, sonarqube, final

Example:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    FOO(4), BAR(7);

    public final int externalValue;

    private TestEnum(int externalValue) {
        this.externalValue = externalValue;
    }
}
```

Notice how there is no getExternalValue() method. Since the externalValue field is final, there's no risk of it getting modified. Running code like this through Sonar gives me a "Variable 'externalValue' must be private and have accessor methods" error.

Assume I'm a total moron, and explain: why do I absolutely need to implement and use an accessor for externalValue?

It's difficult to explain why, but the way the Java Bean pattern went from a clever construct to being a universal law, somehow upsets me. I just feel it shouldn't have to be necessary always.

Comment: This looks like a sonar specific problem, not a java one.

Comment: This is not an error according to Java; it must be something enforced by Sonar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sonar rule is simply wrong in this case; it's not even possible for an enum to conform to the JavaBean spec (since it requires a public constructor)

This always happens with static code analyzers; you can selectively disable certain warnings using a `// NOSONAR` comment or a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Comment: I think this is what I wanted to hear. :) I just think that if it was ok for an enum constant to have public final fields with accessors it shouldn't be that difficult to adjust the inspection in Sonar accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you see official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Every instance final variable is declared private and their accessors are defined. So, may be it just has to be so?